# Removing index.php from my magento store without .htaccess and Allowoverrride All

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I am trying to remove index.php from urls from magento store installed on ubuntu 14.02 with apache2 installed php Version 7

Adding following lines of code to .htaccess is working fine but at the cost of server performance and few more issue. As to make this .htaccess code work I had to add Allowoverride All to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file.

Is there any other way to remove index.php from urls without .htaccess and `Allowoverride All`

Also when I access the site with https://www.rightwood.in all the links when clicked are getting redirected to homepage. Without https its working fine. 
Please give me the solution

I also have magento.conf file created before installing magento.

/etc/apache2/site-available folder as below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I don't get this. You want to remove index.php from appearing in the url, but you'll still be needing the index.php right?

Comment: I want to completely remove index.php from urls. I don`t need them at all.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to achieve the [Human-readable urls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL). In PHP the normal way to do it is using the Apache mod_rewrite as you did.

The https problem is probably related to a different htaccess or apache conf file (your conf only applies to non-https port 80). Look for a virtualhost with ":443" part.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the URLs go the following tends to work.

Log-in Magento Admin.
Go to System -> Configuration -> Web.
From Search Engine Optimization tab Use Web Server Rewrites select YES.
Make sure your Secure and Unsecure base URLs should end with “/”.